To break Javascript string based on delimeter
I have a string "perm=delete;search;update;view-shielded;roles=Admin;CustomerService" and want to convert it as "perm=delete;search;update;view-shielded/roles=Admin;CustomerService".
I try regex but no luck. Please help me with regex.

Where is that string coming from? It is always complicated to parse an encoded string when it is encoded with an unknown schema. You don't need regex for this: simply split the string by ; and process individual entries.

You could try a regex. Here you replace ; followed by a word and =:


const str = 'perm=delete;search;update;view-shielded;roles=Admin;CustomerService';

const result = str.replace(/;(?=\w+=)/g, '/');

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));



